Linear Regression with gaussian mixture prior
In linear regression, we assume that the output variable is Normally distributed, i.e., $p(y) = N (y | \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}, \sigma^2_y)$. I want to assign a mixture of Gaussian prior to each element of $\mathbf{w}$ such that $p(w_j | z_j=k) = N(w_j | \mu_k, \sigma_k^2)$ where prior $p(z_j=k) = \pi_k$ for $k=1:K$. My goal is to infer $K$ center points $\{\mu_k\}$, clustering the elements of $\mathbf{w}$ that maximizes the likelihood of ouptut variable given a set of $ \mathbf{x}_i, y_i$ pairs. I will then use those cluster centers as quantization levels. I tried to use EM algorithm to do this but couldn't derive the posterior distrubitions. Is there any similar model in the literature that I can refer to? Any help is appreciated.
